# Use image uploaded through HTML DOM file uploader in p5js

Tags: javascript, html, css, p5.js

I am attempting to allow users to upload their image file through DOM file uploader ( that is `<input type="file"></input>`) but after I do that I am unsure how to move the image to JavaScript and process it using p5.js. How do I convert an HTML file to a p5.js file or an array of pixels, or really anything I can work with or read as values in JavaScript?

First I restricted the element to only accept `.png` and `.jpg` files.

Then I tried using `.file[0]` syntax and tried to load the image through its path using `.value` inside of the `loadImage()` function.

Neither works, and I am just generally unsure as to what to do from this point.

```
<div id="uploadMenu">
  <h4>Please select your image file:</h4>
  <input accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" type="file" id="imageUpload">
  <button onclick="fileToGrid()">Done</button>
  <script>
  </script>
  <script>
  let thisWindow = document.getElementById("uploadMenu");
  let windowWidth = thisWindow.style.width;
  console.log(windowWidth);
  thisWindow.style.left = `${innerWidth/2 - 100}px`
  thisWindow.style.top = `${innerHeight/2 - 50}px`
  </script>
</div>
```

```
function fileToGrid() {
  let uploadFromHTML = document.getElementById("imageUpload");
  let uploadedImage = loadImage(uploadFromHTML.value);
  let imageW = uploadedImage.width;
  let imageH = uploadedImage.height;
  console.log(imageW, imageH); 
// the end goal is to convert this image to an array of its pixel values
}
```

Comment: Also I am not using jQuery, mostly because I don't really understand what it is yet, and I am not sure if it is worth learning about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it has been a while since I posted this but I figured it out.

So we first find the upload dom element, in this example mine's id was called just "upload".

```
const selectedFile = document.getElementById('upload');
```

We then get the file that was uploaded

```
const myImageFile = selectedFile.files[0];
```

We can then create a URL to the image by doing the following.

```
let urlOfImageFile = URL.createObjectURL(myImageFile);
```

If we use p5.js we can now do this to get a p5jsImage object.

```
let imageObject = loadImage(urlOfImageFile);
```

I would recommend creating a callback function on this if you want to then draw the image because it might not be loaded in right away. All together this becomes this:

```
const selectedFile = document.getElementById('upload');
const myImageFile = selectedFile.files[0];
let urlOfImageFile = URL.createObjectURL(myImageFile);
let imageObject = loadImage(urlOfImageFile, () => {image(imageObject, 0, 0)});
```

Alternatively, you can also use that same URL as a src for an image dom element.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `createFileInput()` function. Reference is [here](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createFileInput).

From that page:

```
let img;

function setup() {
  input = createFileInput(handleFile);
  input.position(0, 0);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  if (img) {
    image(img, 0, 0, width, height);
  }
}

function handleFile(file) {
  print(file);
  if (file.type === 'image') {
    img = createImg(file.data);
    img.hide();
  } else {
    img = null;
  }
}
```

The example on that page shows how to create a file input in P5.js and then get the image from that.

You can probably do the same thing with an existing file input in the DOM.

Comment: Hello, think it could work but I am looking for a different way to do this without importing the dom library. It just doesn't feel good to import the whole library just for 1 function

Comment: @VadimKim You can look at how the library does it behind the scenes. If I were you I would just use the library though.